# How to insert data with forgein key using REST API - Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, rest

I've created my REST API that connect with my MYSQL database. It supports GET, PUT, DELETE and POST methods. Everything works fine, but when I'm trying to POST data to a table that contain forgein key I get:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column
> 'id_companies' cannot be null

I'm trying to POST data using Postman(through body or/and JSON raw)

I've seen similar problems on the Internet but I didn't find a solution to my specific problem.
I'm Using maven and lombok.

**Entity User:**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_users")
    private Integer idUser;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Company.class)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "companyUsers")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_companies")
    private Company companies;
}
```

**UserRepository:**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
    public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

**Entity Company:**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_companies")
    private Integer idCompany;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "nip")
    private String nip;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "companies")
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "companyUsers")
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

**CompanyRepository:**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "companies", path = "companies")
    public interface CompanyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Company, Integer> {
}
```

**---EDITED---**

**sample data I am trying to add via Postman POST**

Trying to create user with id_companies = 2(I'm sure it exists in my batabase)

```
{
    "id_users": 7,
    "firstName": "Joe",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "phoneNumber": "565345765",
    "id_companies": 2,
}
```

I've tried POSTing it without "id_users" because its AUTO_INCREMENT, but the same problem keeps happening.

Comment: How does the data look like you are posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I understand You may have done wrong in your controller class.

If you want to create a user when posting your entity. At first, you have to save your user in your controller class.

```
company.setUsers(userRepository.save(company.getUser));
return companyRepository.save(company);
```

If you want to use existing users then you have to load user using id in your controller.

Comment: But I don't have a controller class. I've created api using @RepositoryRestResource annotation, so my only files are Entity and Repository. That means if I want to perform POST operations on my REST API i need to add one?

Comment: So you want to create a user when you are creating a company or you want to use an existing user from a database?

Comment: I want to create a user and add him to an existing company. So lets say I have Company_A and new person is getting employed. So while looking at users profile I can see what company is he working for.

Comment: At first I didn't fully understand Your answer, but I've added transient Integer with Objects ID and added Your piece of code and it works. :)